# Is there a difference between cmd_drain < <(cmd_src) and cmd_drain <<< "$(cmd_src)"?

Tags: bash

The `cmd | read -r var1 var2` construct famously does not work in bash because the read command is executed in a subshell due to piping. I used to use `read -r var1 var2 <<< "$(cmd)"` to get around this, but recently I learned about the `cmd_drain < <(cmd_src)` construct, which seems to work just as well: `read -r var1 var2 < <$(cmd)`.

Is there a difference between these two solutions? There does not *seem* to be any difference in the trivial case:

```
$ hd < <(echo Hello)
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 0a                                 |Hello.|
00000006
$ hd <<< $(echo Hello)
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 0a                                 |Hello.|
00000006
```

I also tried some special characters and got the same results. My gut feeling is that the result will always be the same expect that `cmd_drain <<< "$(cmd_src)"` will first run `cmd_src` and buffer the whole result in memory before feeding it to `cmd_drain`, while `cmd_drain < <(cmd_src)` will continously feed the output of `cmd_src` into `cmd_drain`. I assume it behaves like `cmd_src | cmd_drain` except that `cmd_src` will be run in a sub-shell instead of `cmd_drain`. Is my assumption correct?

Bonus question: Is quoting necessary around the `$()` construct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct. In `cmd_drain < <(cmd_src)` (aka [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), combined with normal redirection), Bash will replace `<(cmd_src)` with the path to a file, from which the output of `cmd_src` can be read. From the docs:

> The process list is run asynchronously, and its input or output
>   appears as a filename. This filename is passed as an argument to the
>   current command as the result of the expansion. If the `>(list)` form
>   is used, writing to the file will provide input for list. If the
>   `<(list)` form is used, the file passed as an argument should be read
>   to obtain the output of list.

In `cmd_drain <<< "$(cmd_src)"`,  `<<< ...` is treated like any other [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings), so:

> The word undergoes tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion,
>   command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal.
>   Pathname expansion and word splitting are not performed. The result is
>   supplied as a single string, with a newline appended, to the command
>   on its standard input [...]

So you don't need to quote `$()` there, but specifically because the here string `<<<` syntax doesn't do word splitting or filename expansion. Usually, you'd have to.

---

Note again the last sentence of the here string documentation - a newline is appended:

```
bash-5.0$ od -c <<< $(printf %s foo)
0000000   f   o   o  \n
0000004
bash-5.0$ od -c < <(printf %s foo)
0000000   f   o   o
0000003
```

Whether or not that matters is up to what you're running.

In `hd <<< $(echo Hello)`, the command substitution removes the trailing newline output by `echo`, and the here string adds a newline, effectively giving you the same output. But, as the above example shows, this removal/addition of newlines can be tricky, and you need not get exactly what `cmd_src` output.

Comment: The implementation *is* substantively different in ways I don't see this answer currently addressing -- with `<<<"$(...)"`, the content is collected as a whole written to a seekable temporary file (only available for use after completely finished generation); with `< <(...)`, it's streamed over a FIFO (so content becomes available as it's generated, rather than needing the writing process to finish before the reading process can start) and never touches disk.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy this difference was already mentioned in my question as an assumption - although the here-string creating a temporary file was not. In fact, I mistakenly assumed that the here-string will be buffered in memory, not on disk.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the info, but is that documented behaviour? The undocumented side-effects of the particular implementation may change without notice, and for all I know, bash may use different implementations for different OS as well.

Comment: @Olorin, undocumented, implementation-defined, and subject-to-change, indeed. (That said, on systems using tmpfs the temporary-file approach typically microbenchmarks *faster* than a process substitution generating the same output due to the avoided `fork()`, and there aren't any portable means I'm aware of to create a seekable file that *isn't* represented in the filesystem layer, so I'd be surprised to see much change any time soon; the approaches each have unique advantages provided by their present implementations).